# LINQ vs. nHibernate

Tags: linq, nhibernate, orm

Question: Until now, I didn't know LINQ was an ORM tool. I always saw it as some new kind of SQL query language. So I very recently started using nHibernate.


So my question:
What would be the advantages and disadvantages of LINQ in comparison to nHibernate?

As far as I found out, the differences are that LINQ requires .NET > 2.0 (unless you hack it, which is unsafe and illegal), while nHibernate works with >=2.0.

And that for LINQ, you need to have a  vendor/3rd party LINQ provider dll if you don't use MS-SQL.

What I don't know in particular is which one is faster/easier, and whether there are LINQ providers for all databases supported by nHibernate, and how well LINQ works with mono.

Comment: Just to clarify, LINQ was part of the .Net 3 framework.

Comment: Ok, you're busy confusing to things "Linq" which is the query language and "Linq to SQL" which is an ORM. You can use Linq to query NHibernate if you choose...

Comment: I think I'm going to stay with nHibernate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971/nhibernate-vs-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linq isn't an ORM tool. Linq2Sql and the Entity framework are Microsoft ORM tools using Linq. I found [this article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/01/Comparing-NHibernate-EF-4) comparing NHibernate to Entity Framework 4,0 quite enlightening.

To summarise: NHibernate, is long established and tested and Fluent is a joy to use. Unfortunately NHibernate suffers in the documentation dept, but is OS so you can dig into the code.
EF 1.0 was horrendous, but 4.0 is much better. It's a MS product so is heavily evangelised, supported and there are many examples out on the web. 4.0 is still beta for now.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ is not an ORM. LINQ is just a query technology/library with special syntax in C# and LINQ and NHibernate are complementary technologies. There is even L[INQ2NHiernate](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQToNHibernate.ashx).

LINQ2SQL is an ORM. 
With respect to speed, I would not worry too much about it unless you are making stock exchange software or something like that, where milliseconds are absolutely crucial. I believe even StackOverflow runs on LINQ2SQL, or did at some point, but I might be wrong.

Comment: OK, so with LINQ I meant LINQ2SQL ;-))
I read somewhere else they are switching from LINQ to nHibernate for performance reasons. So I'm not sure it's not important.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 linq providers for NHibernate. They support all the database NHibernate supports

Answer (score 1):

Remember that LinqToSql is really LinqToMsSqlServer - you're locked in if you take that route...